React Native Gitlab Ci Read Env. Vars
Using fastlane, I deploy react native applications to appcenter with gitlab. The process is working. However, gitlab cannot read environment variables on ci. The application builds without these values. However, if I build with the same fastlane configuration in my locale, it can read from the .env file. But I don't want to put the .env file in git. How can I solve this?
I expect the application to be able to read environment variables on gitlab ci without any problems

UPDATE: The DevOps team has not added environment variables to the runner!
